# Joi validation for regex pattern

Tags: node.js, express, joi

Is there a method in Joi that makes the string match a regex pattern?

```
const pattern = /^[0-9+]{7}-[0-9+]{1}$/

const schema = Joi.object({
  phone: Joi.string().regex(pattern)
})
```

I've searched the documentation, and researched a lot but couldn't find anything.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation It has to look like:

```
const pattern = /^[0-9+]{7}-[0-9+]{1}$/

const schema = Joi.object({
  phone: Joi.string().pattern(new RegExp(pattern))
})
```

https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.3.0